# JavaScript / Jquery exchange img png source with gif

Tags: javascript, jquery, png, gif

I am trying to Exchange the src of an Image tag on a click Event, the Image src is a png file, but if I click on the Image the source shall Change to a give file.

```
        <img src="images/eye.png" alt="Logo"
             id="sidebar-collapse img-logo-main-page"
             width="80">
```

And this is the JavaScript, I get the console Output in the console but Nothing changes:

```
const gifEgg = {

    elements: {
        logo: $('#img-logo-main-page'),
        logoOverlay: $('#sidebar-image-collapse')
    },

    addGif () {
        this.elements.logoOverlay.click(() => {
            console.log("clicked");
            this.elements.logo.attr('src', '../images/eyes_move.gif');
        });
    }

};

gifEgg.addGif();
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's correct "../images/eyes_move.gif" instead "images/eyes_move.gif"?

Comment: yes even so shouldn't it return an error message or atleast a warning, so you say that the function should work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are treating an `id` like a `class`. You gave the image an `id` of `sidebar-collapse img-logo-main-page`, but are trying to refer to it with `#img-logo-main-page`. An element can only have **one** id, but can have many classes. If you gave it a `class name` of `sidebar-collapse img-logo-main-page`, you could refer to it with `.img-logo-main-page` (any one or more of its classes), but an `id` must be unique and each element can only have one id.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/658687/pexels-photo-658687.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" alt="Logo"
                 id="img-logo-main-page"
                 width="80">
               <button id="sidebar-image-collapse">
               Change Image Source
               </button>
    <script>
    const gifEgg = {

        elements: {
            logo: $('#img-logo-main-page'),
            logoOverlay: $('#sidebar-image-collapse')
        },

        addGif () {
            this.elements.logoOverlay.click(() => {
                console.log("clicked");
                this.elements.logo.prop('src', 'http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3jbHdEj7o2k/Uk6zNIfJkqI/AAAAAAAAB5s/zf7UzbSkp80/s200/zrikh+ajig.gif');
            });
        }

    };

    gifEgg.addGif();
    </script>
```